# How to add a N:1 reference or inject a field from outside with Newtonsoft JSON?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

What is a clean way to serialize/deserialisze class A? There is a N:1 reference to class B I don't want to have multiple times.

I'm thinking about ContractResolver or IsReference.

```
public class A
{
    public B B { get; set; }
    public C[] Cs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    // Serialize me only one time
}

public class C
{
    // Need reference to B here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
public class B { }

public class C
{
    public B B { get; }
    public C(B b) { B = b; }
}
```

does:

```
{
  "B": {
    "$id": "1"
  },
  "Cs": [
    {
      "B": {
        "$ref": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "B": {
        "$ref": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```